# What is the minimum thickness for stainless steel crucible to melt aluminum

Tags: metallurgy

I am planning to make a stainless steel crucible (air-tight) to melt aluminum. Aluminum is known to oxidize in presence of air. I therefore want to create a custom crucible made with sheet metal stainless steel. What is the recommended thickness of sheetmetal in this case?

I shall be cladding the crucible with refractory material to ensure no heat losses from the stainless steel crucible. The crucible shall hold roughly 10-15kg of Aluminum. As per the comments I yet have to see now to have the crucible vacuumed to ensure no gasses are present or employing a one way valse, so that it doesn't become a dangerous to operate.

Comment: good question. keep in mind that you would need a pressure-regulator such as a check valve if you going to be making it air tight to ensure the gasses get vented out while heating (gas expands considerably) , otherwise it could be disastrous.

Comment: How large??? Are you melting 1 kg or 1,000? BTW, if it's covered, how is it heated? If electrical, what insulation?...

Comment: it is perfectly possible to melt aluminium in a normal, open crucible even in air. Search YouTube for gazillions of examples. The losses to oxidation are small and not worth trying to eliminate. Plus, extreme heat + sealed vessel is a bomb, not a cool chemistry experiment.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik 10kg of Aluminium, the stainless steel cruicible is covered but it is heated from the bottom, The insulation would be in the sides to mitigate the losses.

Comment: @matt_black, I am meting aluminum cans which are more prone to oxidation (even when crushed) compared to cast aluminum. I don't have any cast aluminium laying around to melt before adding cans.

Comment: @metron Even so, you don't need a sealed vessel. Which is really dangerous for other reasons.

Comment: When I search "crucible melt" on the net ,hundreds show up. Essentially all are silicon carbide  or ceramic . It may be simpler to do something the way everyone else does it. However ,professionally I would make the crucible of HK 40 about 1/2 " thick ( cast 310 SS with 0.4 % C).

Comment: @blacksmith37, that is the answer I was looking for. Ceramic won't last longer. I want to add actuators and strirrer so I want to custom make it so the pouring is done automatically. I don't have a helper or anyone who could assist me during casting so that's why I decided to make it with actuators with some added safety offcourse.